# Does Scalding support record filtering via predicate pushdown w/Parquet?

Tags: scalding, parquet

There are obvious speed benefits from not having to read records that would fail a filter.  I see Spark support for it, but I haven't found any documentation on how to do it w/Scalding.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no support for this in scalding-parquet yet. We at Tapad started working on implementing Predicate support in scalding. Once we get something working we'll share it.

We have implemented our own ParquetAvroSource that can read/store avro records in parquet. It's possible to use column projection and read only columns/fields required to a scalding job. In some cases using this feature jobs read only 1% of the input bytes.

Comment: Hi Oleksii, do you think it's possible to share your ParquetAvroSource solution? I would love to use the Avro object model and parquet storage together in scalding. Thanks

Comment: I've created a branch in my own fork of scalding with ParquetAvroSource and Projection. It's not complete to make it a pull request into scalding as our tests are in scala test but scalding uses specs. Feel free to grab the code from my fork and ask questions - https://github.com/epishkin/scalding/tree/parquet_avro/scalding-parquet

Answer (score 0):

Predicate pushdown was added to Scalding, but it is not documented yet.
For more details see [scalding issue  #1089](https://github.com/twitter/scalding/issues/1089)